Do frozen fries need a hechsher
According to Halacha, does a bag of frozen fries from a non Jewish store need a Hechsher? Or no, is it kosher without one?

Definitely needs...otherwise they're prefried in non-kosher oils

As the comment said – they come prefried and could absolutely have used non-kosher oil. Goodness yes, they need a hechsher.
The OU and the like have their lists of items not requiring a hechsher. Even if you want to step beyond that, the London Beth Din is willing to allow a few more things in the UK without a hechsher, based on their typical ingredients and processing conditions. But not everything. Have a look at: https://www.kosher.org.uk/koshersearch . If they say "this product requires a hechsher", or "the following brands aren't kosher", that means there's a very good reason why. And that's precisely what they say about "chips" (which in the US are called "french fries.")
Please check those lists before asking about every product under the sun.
